# Should I set up ELK Stack in the same VPS?

Tags: elastic-stack

currently I'have been setting up ELK Stack with docker. I've deployed those dockers to my VPS. It works well. But I'm still concern about the performance if I use ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) to run in the same VPS. Are there any recommendations for deploying ELK Stack?

Thanks for any help!